# selenium sendkeys() to write email into outlook

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

how can I insert a table into outlook based on data fetched from the database by using selenium?

I am using send keys() to write data into outlook but I need data in form of table or grid view with column names.

I am able to fetch data and send into outlook as a send key(data), but the tabular form is a requirement.

Comment: You can simulate a mouse click on the table button to insert then insert data into that table.

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OutlookEX UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/files/file/381-outlookex/).

Prepare body of mail as html:

```
local $Array[][] = [[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]

local $content = ""

for $i=0 to UBound($Array)-1
    $content &= "<tr>"
    for $j = 0 to UBound($Array,2)-1
        $content &= "<td>" & $Array[$i][$j] & "</td>"
    Next
    $content &= "</tr>"
Next

$html = "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>" & $content & "</table>"
```

And use _OL_Wrapper_SendMail fuction:

```
#include <OutlookEx.au3>
$oOL = _OL_Open()
_OL_Wrapper_SendMail($oOL, "John Doe", "", "", $html, "", $olFormatHTML, $olImportanceHigh)
_OL_Close($oOL)
```